# NSString contains anything ".*" to show it

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Hi I have a problem with strings. I want to add :

```
 NSString *termo  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@: %@ ", @"~00000000:",nazwa, @".*"];
```

This .* is anything. How can I use it?

Comment: What is it you want to make happen?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to tell what you're asking. Can you clarify what you want the output of your code to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, however your comment "I have some string which I get from server. I want to parse this string with this" seems to suggest:

1. that you have a string obtained from somewhere;
2. this string should contain the text you have stored in the variable `nazwa`; and
3. you wish to find the text that follows whatever `nazwa` contains.

If this *guess* is correct then the following code fragment might help, it **does not** contain any checks you need to make to verify the input actually contains what you are looking for and is followed by something - check the documentation for the methods used to see what they return if they don't locate the text etc.:

```
// a string representing the input
NSString *theInput = @"The quick brown fox";
// nazwa - the text we are looking for
NSString *nazwa = @"quick";
// locate the text in the input
NSRange nazwaPosition = [theInput rangeOfString:nazwa];
// a range contains a location (offset) and a length, so
// adding these finds the offset of what follows
NSUInteger endofNazwa = nazwaPosition.location + nazwaPosition.length;
// extract what follows
NSString *afterNazwa = [theInput substringFromIndex:endofNazwa];
// display
NSLog(@"theInput '%@'\nnazwa '%@'\nafterNazwa '%@'", theInput, nazwa, afterNazwa);
```

This outputs:

```
theInput 'The quick brown fox'
nazwa 'quick'
afterNazwa ' brown fox'
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

`.*` is a regular expression that is used to match anything, but if you just want to see if an `NSString` isn't empty, you're better off doing something like this

```
![string isEqualToString:@""]
```

Comment: I want to display the thing which is after nazwa:. That's it.

Comment: I use this thermo to comparing stings.

Comment: the do `[NSString stringWithString:@".*"]`... I don't know why you have all of that other stuff then

Comment: if you want to compare strings, use NSPredicate

Comment: When you say "after nazwa", what do you mean by 'after'?  From what you posted, the thing after nazwa is the literal NSString @".*".

Comment: To find out if a string is not empty, I would go with `[string length] > 0`.  It may be fractionally faster and gives a sensible result if `string` is `nil`.

Comment: I have some string which I get from server. I want to parse this string with this: NSString *termo  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@: %@ ", @"~00000000:",nazwa, @".*"];  and this part: @".*" can be another part of this string.

Comment: This question, this answer and all of John Corbett's comments do not make any sense at all. @virtualer007 please update your question with a real example of input and then add an example of what you want the resulting string to look like.